# Расположение методов в многопоточном приложении

Tags: java, многопоточность

При изучении многопоточности в Java столкнулся с непонятным для меня явлением при перестановке двух методов местами внутри одного блока `if`.

Ниже пример, в котором запускаются 10 потоков (ссылка на пример кода в [GitHub](https://github.com/turchev/thread_example)). Их задача в порядке возрастания Id произвести некую работу, в данном случае вывести сообщение, содержащее Id потока и значение переменной в вспомогательном классе.

Пример содержит три класса:

**Класс Main.**
В нем в цикле создается 10 экземпляров класса `ThreadExample`, которые, в свою очередь являются элементами массива. `Id` первого экземпляра потока, до его старта заносится в переменную вспомогательного класса. После этого поочередно в цикле вызывается метод `start` всех потоков.

```java
package lan.example.thread_example;

public class Main {

    static HelperSingletonBillPugh INSTANCE_TEST_THREAD = HelperSingletonBillPugh.getInstance();    
    static ThreadExample[] myThreads = new ThreadExample[10];
    static final int COUNT = 10;

    public static void main(String[] args) { 

        for (int i = 0; i < COUNT; i++) {
            myThreads[i] = new ThreadExample();
             if (i == 0) {              
                INSTANCE_TEST_THREAD.setCurentThreadId(myThreads[i].getId());
             }
             myThreads[i].start();
        }
    }
}
```

**Класс HelperSingletonBillPugh.**
Это вспомогательный хелпер класс, реализованрый по типу синглетона способом Била Пью. Вроде такой тип реализации синглетона считается потокобезопасным. Класс содержит переменную `curentThreadId` типа `long` с `Id` потока и публичные методы `setCurentThreadId(long threadId)`, `getCurentThreadId()`, `incremenCurentThreadId()` для изменения, чтения и инкремента значения этой переменной.

```java
package lan.example.thread_example;

public class HelperSingletonBillPugh {

    private HelperSingletonBillPugh() {
    }

    private static class SingletonHandler {
        private static final HelperSingletonBillPugh INSTANCE = new HelperSingletonBillPugh();
    }

    public static HelperSingletonBillPugh getInstance() {
        return SingletonHandler.INSTANCE;
    }

    private long curentThreadId = 0L;   // Id потока, который должен выполнить вывод сообщения

    public long getCurentThreadId() {
        return this.curentThreadId;
    }

    public void setCurentThreadId(long threadId) {
        this.curentThreadId = threadId;
    }

    public void incremenCurentThreadId() {
        this.curentThreadId++;
    }
}
```

**Класс ThreadExample.**
Класс наследник `Thread`. В нем вечный цикл, с паузами и постоянным сравнением значения `getId()` потока с переменной `curentThreadId` экземпляра вспомогательного класса `HelperSingletonBillPugh`. Если равенство выполняется, то выводится сообщение, переменная `curentThreadId` увеличивается на 1 и поток завершает работу.

```java
package lan.example.thread_example;

public final class ThreadExample extends Thread {

    static HelperSingletonBillPugh INSTANCE_TEST_THREAD = HelperSingletonBillPugh.getInstance();

    @Override
    public void run() {

        while (true) {

            if (INSTANCE_TEST_THREAD.getCurentThreadId() == this.getId()) {

                // Раскомментируй следующую строку
                //INSTANCE_TEST_THREAD.incremenCurentThreadId();
                System.out.println("Print " + this.getName()
                        + " ### ID:" + this.getId()
                        + " ### getCurentThreadId: " + INSTANCE_TEST_THREAD.getCurentThreadId());

                // Закоментируй следующую строку
                INSTANCE_TEST_THREAD.incremenCurentThreadId();

                break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

В данном примере кода сообщения выводятся последовательно и потоки завершают свою работу, все стабильно от запуска к запуску, вот такой вывод:

```
Print Thread-1 ### ID:11 ### getCurentThreadId: 11
Print Thread-2 ### ID:12 ### getCurentThreadId: 12
Print Thread-3 ### ID:13 ### getCurentThreadId: 13
Print Thread-4 ### ID:14 ### getCurentThreadId: 14
Print Thread-5 ### ID:15 ### getCurentThreadId: 15
Print Thread-6 ### ID:16 ### getCurentThreadId: 16
Print Thread-7 ### ID:17 ### getCurentThreadId: 17
Print Thread-8 ### ID:18 ### getCurentThreadId: 18
Print Thread-9 ### ID:19 ### getCurentThreadId: 19
Print Thread-10 ### ID:20 ### getCurentThreadId: 20
```

Но стоит только переставить местами метод `INSTANCE_TEST_THREAD.incremenCurentThreadId()` и метод `System.out.println()` (в коде помечено где убрать и добавить коммент) и результат становится не стабильным и для меня не понятным, хотя перестановка осуществляется внутри блока `if`. Если быть точнее, то он не всегда стабильный, то есть, несколько запусков может пройти вполне корректно. Вот вывод одного из запусков после перестановки методов местами:

```
Print Thread-1 ### ID:11 ### getCurentThreadId: 12
Print Thread-2 ### ID:12 ### getCurentThreadId: 15
Print Thread-6 ### ID:16 ### getCurentThreadId: 17
Print Thread-5 ### ID:15 ### getCurentThreadId: 16
Print Thread-4 ### ID:14 ### getCurentThreadId: 15
Print Thread-7 ### ID:17 ### getCurentThreadId: 21
Print Thread-3 ### ID:13 ### getCurentThreadId: 21
Print Thread-8 ### ID:18 ### getCurentThreadId: 21
Print Thread-9 ### ID:19 ### getCurentThreadId: 21
Print Thread-10 ### ID:20 ### getCurentThreadId: 21
```

Из примера видно, что потоки выводят сообщения хаотично и значение переменной `getCurentThreadId` временами отличается от `Id` текущего потока более чем на 1. Что-же происходит при изменении местами двух этих методов? Дело в том, что когда `System.out.println()` находится перед `INSTANCE_TEST_THREAD.incremenCurentThreadId()`, то у меня нет ни одного непредсказуемого результата. Можно ли считать это стабильной работой или все-таки эта стабильность обманчива и при неких обстоятельствах пример отработает не корректно?

P/S. На всякий случай уточню. Я немного имею представление про Java Memory Model, оператор `volatile`, блок `synchronize`, про кэши данных и атомарность, правда глубоких знаний пока нет, но добиться гарантированной стабильной работы примера скорее всего смогу. Интересует именно понимание того, какие-такие серьезные изменения происходят при перестановки местами этих двух методов, так влияющие на результат работы примера. И, как следствие, можно ли считать стабильной работу примера в первом случае и почему? Проверял пример на разных операционных системах (Linux Mint 32 и 64 bit, Windows 10 64 bit), но правда только с Oracle JDK.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Дело в том, что операция инкремента не является атомарной, а состоит из двух операций: чтения текущего значения и записи увеличенного значения. Если развернуть ее, то цикл в первом сценарии будет выглядеть так:

```
while (...) {
    <чтение id> // вывод на консоль
    <чтение id> // инкремент, шаг 1
    <запись id> // инкремент, шаг 2
}
```

Такое расположение операций вкупе с хитрым условием `while` по сути служит локом, дающим доступ к телу цикла только одному потоку. Сначала только первый поток заходит внутрь цикла, а остальные просто прокручивают его ("блокируются"). Когда первый поток записывает увеличенный id и выходит из цикла, то уже он начинает прокручивать цикл ("блокируется"), а второй поток заходит внутрь. И так по очереди для всех потоков. Именно за счет инкремента все потоки получают этот доступ последовательно, согласно своим номерам. **Важным здесь является то, что запись id по сути освобождает "лок" текущего потока и "разрешает" выполнение другого потока.** Пока она идет последней в теле цикла, проблем не возникает.

Во втором сценарии цикл выглядит следующим образом:

```
while (...) {
    <чтение id> // инкремент, шаг 1
    <запись id> // инкремент, шаг 2
    <чтение id> // вывод на консоль
}
```

Теперь мы видим, что "лок" освобождается чуть раньше. К чему это может привести? К тому, что между записью id и вторым чтением id **могут начать исполняться другие потоки**, поскольку "лок" свободен и доступ к телу цикла может получить другой поток. Т.е. возникает классическая гонка, в результате которой может происходить следующее:

- поток на втором чтении id может получить уже обновленное значение (это объясняет, например, почему Thread-2 выводит 15, а не 13)
- вывод в консоль может перепутаться из-за того, что другие потоки "встревают" сразу после записи id

  ```
  while (...) {
      <чтение id> // инкремент, шаг 1
      <запись id> // инкремент, шаг 2
      <возможное исполнение других потоков>
      <чтение id> // вывод на консоль (потенциально уже нового значения)
  }
  ```

Сценарий выполнения для приведенного вами в вопросе лога может выглядеть так:

```
все потоки начинают выполнение
все потоки кроме потока 1 "блокируются" на условии while
поток 1 читает id (=11)
поток 1 увеличивает id (=12)
поток 2 "разблокируется"
поток 2 читает id (=12)
поток 1 читает id и выводит на консоль (=12)
поток 1 "засыпает"
поток 2 увеличивает id (=13)
поток 3 "разблокируется"
поток 3 читает id (=13)
поток 3 увеличивает id (=14)
поток 4 "разблокируется"
поток 4 читает id (=14)
поток 4 увеличивает id (=15)
поток 2 читает id и выводит на консоль (=15)
поток 2 "засыпает"
поток 5 "разблокируется"
поток 5 читает id (=15)
поток 5 увеличивает id (=16)
поток 6 "разблокируется"
поток 6 читает id (=16)
поток 6 увеличивает id (=17)
поток 6 читает id и выводит на консоль (=17)
поток 6 "засыпает"

...и так далее
```

Answer (score 6):

На самом деле всё достаточно просто. Вы создаёте несколько потоков, а данный метод разрешает выполняться только 1 с нужным id. Этот id содержится в переменной `INSTANCE_TEST_THREAD.getCurentThreadId()`. Теперь вы меняете местами. Может быть такая ситуация:

```
1 поток зашёл, значение 1
1 поток увеличил значение до 2
2 поток зашёл значение 2
2 поток увеличил значение до 3
1 поток вывел 3 (!!)
2 поток вывел 3 (!!)
3 поток увеличил значение до 4
3 поток вывел 4.
```

Думаю идею вы поняли. Поменяв местами мы делаем гонку потоков с непредсказуемым порядком выполнения, по сути сделав весь код синхронизации нерабочим.